# databricks python: Upload a file to sharepoint using create_upload_session() using dbfs path

Tags: python, pyspark, sharepoint, databricks

I'm trying to upload a large file(~500 MB) using the code mentioned in the below github url

[URL](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/sharepoint/files/upload_large.py)

My file is in databricks dbfs, here is the file path '/dbfs/to/dest/sample_large_file.csv'

I'm pasting part of the code below where the issue is happening.

```
local_path='/dbfs/to/dest/sample_large_file.csv'
target_folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(sharepoint_path)
target_folder.files.create_upload_session(local_path, size_chunk, print_upload_progress).execute_query()
```

below is the error I'm getting.

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dbfs/to/dest/sample_large_file.csv`

Could anyone please assist on this. I need to upload file from dbfs path only.

I have tried using the path `dbfs:/to/dest/sample_large_file.csv` and `dbfs:/dbfs/to/dest/sample_large_file.csv`, but still it didn't work.

Comment: are you running this on the shared cluster?

Comment: Yes @AlexOtt, I'm running this on the shared cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Local file system isn't available (including `/dbfs`) on the shared clusters - it's documented [here](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/configure.html#shared-limitations).

Theoretically you can read the whole file as text, and then do `.collect`, but most probably it will overload your session and crash it.

Comment: It is not working even for the single user cluster. I'm getting the same error. FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: